# How to Access Athena QueryString From CloudFormation in Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena

AWS-loaded question, but does anyone know what the proper way to access an Athena Query String (in CloudFormation) in Lambda?

I have set up both the Athena NamedQuery and the Lambda in CloudFormation. Abstracting out some of the more project-specific details, the general form I have is:

```
MyQuery:
 Type: AWS::Athena::NamedQuery
 Properties:
   Database: "mydatabase"
   Name: "DataQuery"
   QueryString: SELECT * FROM mydatabase

MyLambda:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  Handler: 'handlers.migration_handler'
  Runtime: python3.6
  CodeUri:
    Bucket: BATS::SAM::CodeS3Bucket
    Key: BATS::SAM::CodeS3Key
  Description: Migrates data from output of Athena query to S3
  Policies:
    - AmazonS3FullAccess
    - AWSLambdaExecute
    - AmazonAthenaFullAccess
  Environment:
    Variables:
      MY_QUERY:
        Ref: MyQuery
```

When I'm writing the handler for the lambda, I want to call:

```
athena_client = boto3.client('athena')
response = athena_client.start_query_execution(
      QueryString = os.environ['MY_QUERY']
      ResultConfiguration = {'OutputLocation: 's3://my-bucket'}
)
```

However, QueryString needs to be a string, so this currently isn't working. I want to access the QueryString property in MY_QUERY, and I feel like I'm so close but I'm not quite sure how to get that last step. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out yesterday (or more specifically, my teammate figured it out).

Boto3 happens to have another method called `get_named_query(NamedQueryId)`, and that returns a dictionary in the form of:

```
{
'NamedQuery': {
    'Name': 'string',
    'Description': 'string',
    'Database': 'string',
    'QueryString': 'string',
    'NamedQueryId': 'string'
}
```

Thus, my code worked when I modified my lambda handler to:

```
athena_client = boto3.client('athena')

query_info = athena_client.get_named_query(
    NamedQueryId = os.environ['MY_QUERY']
)

response = athena_client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString = query_info['NamedQuery']['QueryString']
    ResultConfiguration = {'OutputLocation: 's3://my-bucket'}
)
```